# rake db:seed failing on pending migration when there are none

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm running a (previously working fine) seed file like so:
[image: Seed failure trace]

I check to see if there are pending migrations with `rake db:migrate:status` and all migrations are "up".

For additional context, here's what led me to this point:

1. Working in 6 year old Rails Code
2. Start a branch for feature "A"
3. Wrap feature "A". Checkout new branch for Feature "B"
   Master --> "A" --> "B"
4. Finish feature "B" + commit
5. Checkout "A" for refactoring
6. Add column to migration for "A" (nothings been merged with master yet, so I figure I can drop and rebuild my dev db no problem *WRONG*)
7. Wrap refactoring for "A" + Commit
8. Checkout Branch "B"
   9 Merge "A" into "B"
9. Drop DB
10. Create DB with `bin/rake db:create db:schema:load` All good
11. Run rake db:seed and nothing happens.
12. Run with trace and get the error you see above.
13. Have no idea what's causing this.

**More Context**

-Ruby 2.3.1
-Rails 4.2.7.1
-Postgresql 9.6.2

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like you actually have a problem; `abort_if_pending_migrations` just happens to be the last trace line that even a successful seed outputs. A fully-working Rails env on my machine spits out the same output, but works just fine (complete with 0 error code):

```
$ be rake db:seed --trace
** Invoke db:seed (first_time)
** Execute db:seed
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
$ echo $?
0
```

For the record, it's expected for `db:seed` to normally print no output.

Comment: To add onto this - it can help to put a few messages in your seed, like a = User.new and then puts 'user 1 saved' if a.save

Comment: Thanks guys *derp*